# Change "NavigateUrl" in for searchcenter picture

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, branding, search-center

I want to change the `NavigateUrl` property of the searchcenter site. Notice that I don't want to change this property for the other sites. Any ideas?

Comment: You should update the master page for SearchCenter site. And place the new URL.

Comment: Yes, the minimal.master right? But I'll get errors of missing content placeholders and when I add the missing placeholders I don't get an error but it's seems like it's changing from sp2013 settle.Master to sp2010 masterpage. How should I know in what order the placeholders shall be and so on?

Comment: Identify which is the current master page the search center site is using. Then edit that in SPD and update the URL.

Comment: I tried to go to "rootsite/site/search/_catalogs/masterpage"  where my search center are located. found the seattle masterpage which is active on that website. I edited the NavigateUrl to "~sitecollection/" and saved. A warningprompt appeard saying that its no longer based on the site definition. I click ok and then refresh. But it still doesent work?